# Multiple Regression with Parallel Slopes Model

Tags: r, regression, correlation

[image]

I am trying to find correlations and quantitive relations between two variables taking into account a third variable. I am clearly doing something wrong or interpreting the results wrong, as it does not make any sense.
I am using R markdown and the following is my data sample

```r
library(dplyr)
library(pixiedust)

:Flexion_Degrees    :Load_Direction:    :Load_N:    :Osteotomy_Type:    :PTS_Degrees:   :Paper: ATT_ACL:
30  Anterior    134 Native  0   Nelitz  5.5
90  Anterior    134 AOWO    10  Nelitz  3.8
30  Anterior    134 AOWO    15  Nelitz  5.2
90  Anterior    134 AOWO    15  Nelitz  3.1
15  UNLOADED    18  Native  8   Martineau   0.6
15  UNLOADED    18  AOWO    12.1    Martineau   2.1
15  UNLOADED    18  AOWO    16.3    Martineau   3.2
15  Anterior    18  Native  8   Martineau   -2.1
15  Anterior    108 AOWO    12.1    Martineau   1.4
15  Anterior    209 AOWO    16.3    Martineau   6.7
30  Axial_Compression   400 ACWO    9.9 Imhoff, Comer   3.8
30  Axial_Compression   400 ACWO    0   Imhoff, Comer   2.4
30  Axial_Compression   400 ACWO    9.9 Imhoff, Comer   6.3
```

I used the following code to get the correlation between ATT_ACL and PTS_Degree:

```
ATT %>% 
  get_correlation(formula = ATT_ACL ~ PTS_Degrees)
```

The result is 0.09

I interpreted it as per the following : Correlation analysis revealed a weakly positive correlation between ATT_ACL and the PTS degrees (r =0.09)

Then I used a parallel slopes model to find the relation between `PTS_degrees` and `ACL_ATT` under various loading conditions (Load_Direction) and I used the following code:

```r
ATT_model1_interaction <- lm(ATT_ACL ~ PTS_Degrees * Load_Direction, data = ATT)

# Get regression table:

    get_regression_table(ATT_model1_interaction)
    dust(ATT_model1_interaction) %>% 
      sprinkle(cols = c("estimate", "std.error", "statistic"),
               round = 3) %>% 
      sprinkle(cols = "p.value", fn = quote(pvalString(value)))
```

Results:

```
                                             term       estimate std.error statistic p.value
1                                          (Intercept)    3.331      0.73     4.564 < 0.001
2                                          PTS_Degrees    0.031     0.084     0.366    0.72
3             Load_Direction Anterior_Axial compression    2.669     2.204     1.211    0.24
4                      Load_Direction Axial_Compression   -1.225      1.27    -0.964    0.35
5                               Load_Direction UNLOADED   -5.162     4.523    -1.141    0.27

6 PTS_Degrees:Load_Direction Anterior_Axial compression   -0.161     0.306    -0.526     0.6
7          PTS_Degrees:Load_Direction Axial_Compression    0.146      0.17     0.861     0.4
8                   PTS_Degrees:Load_Direction UNLOADED    0.282     0.364     0.775    0.45
```

My interpretation of the results was as per the following:

Parallel slopes models revealed that when PTS was zero,  the mean reported ATT  under various loading conditions was as per the following; (Intercept) anterior load 3.33 mm (p < 0.001), combined anterior and Axial load 6.02 mm (p = 0.2), axial load 2.1 mm (p = 0.4), and unloading   (-1.83 mm (p = 0.3)). Increasing the PTS one degree, increases ATT 0.03 mm under all tested loading conditions (p = 0.7).

What is the correct interpretation? And what is wrong in my analysis?

[image]

Comment: Hello! This question is very hard to follow how it is written currently. Please review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) to give answerers a good place to start. If you need to provide data to us, please use something like `tibble::tribble()` or one of R's built in datasets (e.g. mtcars) in your example.

Comment: I am not really sure how to provide the data. with this tibble::tribble (). I copy paste them and this is how it presents. Would you kindly advise how to do that?

Comment: I have taken a screeenshot of sample of my data , may be you will be able to advise me better how to add this to my question and for future reference as well. and also I added the plot that was created after wards with the this code:

Comment: ggplot(ATT, aes(x = PTS_Degrees, y = ATT_ACL, color = Load_Direction)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  labs(x = "Posterior Tibial Slope", y = "Anterior Tibial Translation", color = "Load Direction") +
  geom_parallel_slopes(se = FALSE)

Comment: Ben Bolker, Thank you for your help and the comment. I expected the numbers to be bigger. Unless everything is correct in the analysis. That should be alright. I have never used Cross Validated. Shall I post my question there then? or it will move automatically? Also, how do I edit the data to present nicely when I post a question?

Answer (score 3):

Trying to replicate the results from what is presented on screen, I noticed that no data is presented for the "Anterior_AxialCompression" load direction.

If you can present your data like this, then it will be easier for people to replicate and provide feedback.

```r
## Data 

dat <- data.frame(flexion_degrees = c(rep(c(30, 90), 4), rep(15, 6), rep(30, 3)),
                  load_direction = c(rep("Anterior", 8), rep("UNLOADED", 3), rep("Anterior", 3), rep("Axial_Compression", 3)),
                  load_n = c(rep(134, 8), rep(18, 4), 208, 209, rep(400, 3)),
                  osteotomy_type = c(rep("Native", 2), rep("AOWO", 6), "Native", "AOWO", "AOWO", "Native", "AOWO", "AOWO", rep("ACWO", 3)),
                  pts_degrees = c(0, 0, 5, 5, 10, 10, 15, 15, 8, 12.1, 16.3, 8, 12.1, 16.3, 9.9, 0, 9.9),
                  paper = c(rep("Nelitz", 8), rep("Martineau", 6), rep("Imhoff", 3)), 
                  att_acl = c(5.5, 4, 0, 4, 5.7, 3.8, 5.2, 3.1, 0.6, 2.1, 3.2, -2.1, 1.4, 6.7, 3.8, 2.4, 6.3))

## Trying to replicate anlaysis

# Note the moderndive::get_correlation() function is just a call to cor with defaults

# all data in the spreadsheet and the Rmarkdown
with(dat, cor(att_acl, pts_degrees))
# only data in the Rmarkdown
with(dat[c(1,6:17),], cor(att_acl, pts_degrees))

# all data in the spreadsheet and the Rmarkdown
lm1 <- lm(att_acl ~ pts_degrees * load_direction, data = dat)
summary(lm1)
# only data in the Rmarkdown
lm1 <- lm(att_acl ~ pts_degrees * load_direction, data = dat[c(1,6:17),])
summary(lm1)
```

Without the data, the conclusion you can draw from the p-values you have shown in the linear model summary is that "there is insufficient evidence to conclude that the interaction of PTS degrees and load direction is a significant predictor of ATT".  Depending on the assumptions of your analysis, your next step might be to fit a model with main effects only or to try a variable transform (e.g. sine of the PTS degrees).